# Missing "key" prop for element. (ReactJS and TypeScript)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am using below code for reactJS and typescript. While executing the commands I  get below error.

I also added the import statement 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
in Index.tsx.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

```
npm start

client/src/Results.tsx
(32,21): Missing "key" prop for element.
```

The file is as below "Results.tsx"

```
import * as React from 'react';
 class Results extends React.Component<{}, any> {

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        topics: [],
        isLoading: false
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});

    fetch('http://localhost:8080/topics')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({topics: data, isLoading: false}));
}

render() {
    const {topics, isLoading} = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Results List</h2>
            {topics.map((topic: any) =>
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-heading" key={topic.id}>{topic.name}</div>
                    <div className="panel-body" key={topic.id}>{topic.description}</div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default Results;
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are rendering an array of elements, so React needs a `key` prop ([see react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)) to identify elements and optimize things.

Add `key={topic.id}` to your jsx:

```
return (
  <div>
    <h2>Results List</h2>
    {topics.map((topic: any) =>
      <div className="panel panel-default" key={topic.id}>
        <div className="panel-heading">{topic.name}</div>
        <div className="panel-body">{topic.description}</div>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: In my case `(react 16.13.1)` key was required not just on the outermost element, but inner elements also.
`<div className="panel-heading">{topic.name}</div>` should be `<div className="panel-heading" key={topic.id}>{topic.name}</div>`. As in the question.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, unless you render inner elements in an array.

Comment: Maybe you are right, I am new to react. Maybe something else was at play too, and setting key to child elements was just superfluous.

Comment: eh, this is on a div but what if you have to put keys on multiple custom components, then TS complains that key isn't a property and you have a chicken and egg situation

Answer (score 0):

This has helped me

React special props should not be accessed
https://deepscan.io/docs/rules/react-bad-special-props