# Can't deploy to Vercel due to missing key error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, vercel

I keep getting an error message on vercel when I want to deploy my website.The error is:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n41BZ.png)

when I deploy it locally, there aren't any problems. I don't know why I'm getting this error.
my ImageScrollbar.jsx file is:

```js
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { Box, Icon, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { ScrollMenu, VisibilityContext } from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';
import { FaArrowAltCircleLeft, FaArrowAltCircleRight } from 'react-icons/fa';

const LeftArrow = () => {
  const { scrollPrev } = useContext(VisibilityContext);

  return (
    <Flex justifyContent='center' alignItems='center' marginRight='1'>
      <Icon
        as={FaArrowAltCircleLeft}
        onClick={() => scrollPrev()}
        fontSize='2xl'
        cursor='pointer'
        d={['none','none','none','block']}
      />
    </Flex>
  );
}

const RightArrow = () => {
  const { scrollNext } = useContext(VisibilityContext);

  return (
    <Flex justifyContent='center' alignItems='center' marginLeft='1'>
      <Icon
        as={FaArrowAltCircleRight}
        onClick={() => scrollNext()}
        fontSize='2xl'
        cursor='pointer'
        d={['none','none','none','block']}
    />
    </Flex>
  );
}
export default function ImageSrollbar({ data }) {
  return (
    <ScrollMenu LeftArrow={LeftArrow} RightArrow={RightArrow} style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }} >
      {data.map((item) => (
        <Box width='910px' itemId={item.id} overflow='hidden' p='1'>
          <Image placeholder="blur" blurDataURL={item.url} src={item.url} width={1000} height={500}  sizes="(max-width: 500px) 100px, (max-width: 1023px) 400px, 1000px" alt=""/>
        </Box>
      ))}
    </ScrollMenu>
  );
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518226/my-create-react-app-is-failing-to-compile-due-to-eslint-error

Comment: You need to add a `key` prop to the `<Box>` components you're mapping. See [Missing "key" prop for element. (ReactJS and TypeScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266018/missing-key-prop-for-element-reactjs-and-typescript).