# React MUI Error Missing "key" prop for element in array react/jsx-key

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, key

```
{
    field: 'deletedAt',
    headerName: 'DeleteAt',
    type: 'actions',
    width: 200,
    editable: false,
    getActions: () => [<GridActionsCellItem icon={<DeleteIcon />} label="Delete" />],
  },
```

```
return (
    <div style={{ height: 720, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGridPro
        rows={customizings}
        columns={columns}
        getRowId={(row) => row._id}
        experimentalFeatures={{ newEditingApi: true }}     
        components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
        initialState={{ pinnedColumns: { right: ['actions'] } }}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

I want to add this icon to the contents of the datagrid table, but I am getting a back key error. How can I solve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing "key" prop for element. (ReactJS and TypeScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266018/missing-key-prop-for-element-reactjs-and-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

Antwort: Name of field must be actions